# Place a RelativeLayout below a LinearLayout inside another LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to place a `RelativeLayout` below a `LinearLayout` that is nested inside another `LinearLayout` and it's not working.

Is there any way I can do that?

I need to keep the ability of settings weights and the ability of placing a Layout (with some transparent background) above another Layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:id="@+id/relative"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <LinearLayout  android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:gravity="center_horizontal" android:orientation="vertical" android:weightSum="800">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:id="@+id/infoCanso" android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@drawable/black_glossy_bg_iphone" android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="90">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/albumBG" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_below="@+id/infoCanso" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="482">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/linearLayout1" android:background="#80ffffff" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:layout_weight="90">

        </LinearLayout>
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" android:id="@+id/LinearLayout01" android:layout_weight="100" android:background="#ffffff">

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50dip" android:id="@+id/volumeBar" android:background="#80000000" android:gravity="center" android:layout_below="@+id/infoCanso">

    </RelativeLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: don't try to use as much layout on your xml it's not good design,if you want such a design means try to use RelativeLayout itself by using android:layout_below propert for the view you need.

Comment: I've already done it using RelativeLayouts but I need to use the layout_weight property from LinearLayouts..
Why it isn't good using LinearLayouts¿?

Comment: Do you get any error or it is not working as per your expectations?

Comment: No error, it's not workink as per my expectations.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your weights add up to 100.  An easy way to do what you're doing is to declare your widths as "0dp" and then use your weights to control the size of your layouts.

I described something similar in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417591/android-fixed-width-edittext-within-tablerow/6417672#6417672)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using the property layout_gravity of the specific layout,
Go to the XML in relativeLayout set the property layout_gravity to 'TOP' like this android:layout_gravity="top"
and to the linearlayout layout_gravity to android:layout_gravity="bottom"

remember the setGravity and layout_gravity are different things !
This can be done using XMl but i dont know in code wise .
Hope i answered your question

Thanx