# Android fixed width EditText within TableRow

Tags: android, android-edittext

I'm completely stuck trying to get fixed width EditText widgets in a TableRow. 
I am attempting to place two EditText side by side with equal width (about 20dip) but no matter which property I try and set the first EditText is way to long and apparently cannot be resized.

Many thanks:

```
<TableRow 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:baselineAligned="false" 
  android:id="@+id/tableRow3" 
  android:gravity="center"
  android:stretchColumns="1" 
  android:layout_width="match_parent">
  <TextView 
    android:id="@+id/textView6" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="1" 
    android:paddingLeft="36dip">
  </TextView>
  <EditText
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/editText2" 
    android:inputType="number" 
    android:layout_width="20dip">
  </EditText>
  <EditText 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/editText1" 
    android:inputType="number"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content">
    <requestFocus></requestFocus>
  </EditText>
</TableRow>
```

Comment: Phil, please mark an answer as correct if it answered your question :) Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I don't know that a TableLayout is the best way to do this, it can be cumbersome unless you're displaying large amounts of data and need to use it.

One of the best ways I've found to ensure that form objects have length distributed the way I want them is by using weight rather than explicitly declaring width.

Try the following:

```
<LinearLayout ... android:orientation="horizontal" ... 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<TextView ... android:layout_width="0dp" ... android:layout_weight="50" />
<TextView ... android:layout_width="0dp" ... android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure to declare the layout width as 0, this will let the layout fill to the weight.

This should create two TextViews next to each other on the screen, both filling 50% of the screen.  You can play with different percentages.  You can also use a LinearLayout as a placeholder with a weight of whatever % you would like to place hold.

Make sure that your "weights" add up to 100 in order to ensure the view will look exactly as you want it to.  It's not necessary, but it's a good convention to know what % of the screen width it will take up.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply, I tried this for EditText which is the components I'm trying to place and it doesn't work. I think I may be missing something pretty fundamental to be honest. I will go back to tutorials and run through them. thanks for the reply though :)

Comment: Not sure why Pheonixblade is setting the weight at 50, but if you declare the width 0 and use weight the way you normally should (with 1, or 2 etc) then it displayes equal column widths. If you set the width to say fill_parent, then the content in the TextView determines the column width.

Comment: I just use 100 as the weightSum as a standard to make sure I know what's going on, you can use any weight you want. :)

Comment: >Phoneixblade9- its working for me.I change my application layout settings as u mentioned.Its working me.Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

[Based on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1408781/android-how-do-i-prevent-an-edittext-from-resizing-itself-when-the-user-is-typ)

Add this property on your `EditText`:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

Works for me.