# How do I split a TableRow evenly between both columns?

Tags: android

I am generating TableRows dynamically. For each TableRow, there is a TextView in one column and an EditText in the other. How do I generate the rows such that the TextView takes up half the row and the EditText the other half?

This is what I currently have:

The layout xml file

```
<TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:stretchColumns="*"
        android:id="@+id/formTable" />
```

The Java source file

```
private TreeMap<String, EditText> textData;
...
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    textData = populateMap();
    ...
    TableLayout table = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.formTable);
    configureTableLayout(table,textData);
}

private TreeMap<String, EditText> populateMap() {
    TreeMap<String, EditText> map = new TreeMap<String, EditText>();

    Set<String> dataTypeSet = app.getWorkingDataTypeList();
    for (String dataTypeKey : dataTypeSet) {
        EditText edit = new EditText(this);
        edit.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        edit.setText("0");
        edit.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);
        map.put(dataTypeKey, edit);
    }

    return map;
}

private void configureTableLayout (TableLayout table, 
        Map<String, ? extends View> input) {
    for (Map.Entry<String, ? extends View> entry : input.entrySet()) {
        addTableRow(table, entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}

private void addTableRow(TableLayout table, String dataTypeKey, View v) {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    row.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    TextView textCol = new TextView(this); // left column
    textCol.setText(app.getTypeNameForKey(dataTypeKey));
    textCol.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
    textCol.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 16);
    textCol.setHorizontallyScrolling(true);

    // right column
    TableRow.LayoutParams params = new TableRow.LayoutParams(
            TableRow.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.column = 1;
    v.setLayoutParams(params);

    row.addView(textCol);
    row.addView(v);

    table.addView(row);
}
```

I have read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1666685/android-stretch-columns-evenly-in-a-tablelayout) already, but it's not exactly what I'm looking for. My primary motivation for splitting each row evenly is that if one of the Strings resulting from `app.getTypeNameForKey(dataTypeKey)` (found in `addTableRow()`) is excessively long, it might cause the EditText column to become too small for readability.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Note that [`TableLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) extends `LinearLayout` (as does `TableRow`, as well).  That means any children in the `TableLayout`, and any children in the `TableRow`, may specify the `android:layout_weight` attribute to get the behavior described by Phoenixblade9.  Just set `android:layout_weight="1"` on both the `TextView` and the `EditText`, and you'll get 50% splits.

Comment: Helpful to know, but it isn't working as I expected. Here's my [revised code](http://www.pastie.org/2103086) (revisions are in `populateMap()` (which defines `EditText` behavior) and `addTableRow()` (which defines `TextView` and `TableRow` behavior)). The only other change I've made is removing the `android:stretch_columns="*"` line from the xml file. The behavior of the columns haven't changed yet, and the TextViews are still taking up more than half the space.

Comment: Minor update: I've been trying your method out in isolated xml layout files. Everything works when there is only a `TableRow` with a `TextView` and `EditText`. But once put the `TableRow` in a `TableLayout`, the even column size fails to hold up, reverting back to my original problem. (TL;DR - it works in a single `TableRow`, but not on a `TableRow` in a `TableLayout`)

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems like I can't fight against the fact that the ["width of a column is defined by the row with the widest cell in that column."](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TableLayout.html) I am resorting to adding TableRows to a single LinearLayout, which will work in my case since I want fixed width columns.

Answer (score 6):

From my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6417591/android-fixed-width-edittext-within-tablerow) :

I don't know that a TableLayout is the best way to do this, it can be cumbersome unless you're displaying large amounts of data and need to use it.

One of the best ways I've found to ensure that form objects have length distributed the way I want them is by using weight rather than explicitly declaring width.

Try the following:

```
<LinearLayout ... android:orientation="horizontal" ... 
android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
<TextView ... android:layout_width="0dp" ... android:layout_weight="50" />
<TextView ... android:layout_width="0dp" ... android:layout_weight="50" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Make sure to declare the layout width as 0, this will let the layout fill to the weight.

This should create two TextViews next to each other on the screen, both filling 50% of the screen. You can play with different percentages. You can also use a LinearLayout as a placeholder with a weight of whatever % you would like to place hold.

Make sure that your "weights" add up to 100 in order to ensure the view will look exactly as you want it to.

You can place these LinearLayouts in a TableLayout if you would like to :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Do the weights need to add up to 100, or is it just a proportion? I thought that weighting both at 1 would give you a 50/50 split as well, or if you weighted one at 1, and the other at 2, you'd have the first take up 1/3rd of the screen, and the other 2/3rds. I don't remember, but it's something that can be easily determined empirically.

Comment: So, my app potentially needs to display large amounts of data. I forgot to mention in my original post that I wrapped the TableLayout with a ScrollView. However, I'm going to look into using one-column tables with a TextView and an EditText, though I think that's going to defeat the purpose of a TableLayout.

Comment: @Lawngnomehitman: It's more proportion than it is percent-wise. See [this link for more information](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout-objects.html#linearlayout). In short, layout_weight specifies the "importance" of a view relative to other views, so it doesn't have to add up to 100. If left unset, it defaults to 0.

Comment: Maybe I was mistaken, but making sure it adds up to a specific number is not a bad design strategy to have :)